# Run Symfony app on shared hosting not working

Tags: php, symfony, cpanel, shared-hosting

I want to run my Symfony5 app on shared hosting (cpanel).
On the shared hosting I have the following folder structure:

```
/
/public_html
/symfony
```

When I put the whole project in the public_html folder, it works from https://domain.abc/public but that is not the way it should work as the the other symfony folder shouldn't be visible.

I've put the file from symfony/public folder to the public_html folder
The index.php (with 755 rights) in the /public_html folder is like this:

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/../symfony/vendor/autoload.php';

(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/../symfony/.env');

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

But i get a blank screen when going to https://domain.abc

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation it is best to have `/public_html` be a symlink pointing to `/symfony/public`.

Alternatively, if your hosting provider allows it, you may be able to re-configure the root directory for your domain to be `/symfony/public`.

In either case, start by removing `/public_html` and undo any changes made in `/symfony/public/index.php`.
If you have made no changes within `/symfony/*`, then you only need to run the commands below to create a symlink:

```
rm -r -f /public_html/
ln -s /symfony/public /public_html
```

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/public_html': Permission denied`

Comment: I was able to make the symlink with `ln -s /home/<username>/symfony/public /public_html`

This was missing.