# Change default public folder symfony

Tags: php, apache, symfony, server, cpanel

Always when I need to deploy a symfony project in cpanel, I need to put it on root folder and symfony's public/ in public_html, but this is bad because the files are loose in folder, I want to put the files in a folder like app/, but in main domain we can't change the folder's project.

One day my friend told me how to do this in symfony, I just needed to put public/ in public_html, and all the others files in a folder as app and in public_html I put a new config in .htaccess, but this doens't work with symfony!

I used symfony 5.4
Apache
Cpanel

Comment: Please compare: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69054088/367456 - ist that your scenario? Does it perhaps already answers your question? And call your friend, we don't know what they told you that time.